# Running `composer require ...` fails on post process cache clearing step

Tags: php, symfony, caching, composer-php

I can't seem to be able to complete installation of bundles using

`composer require <bundle-name>` because of these errors:

> [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]   Failed to
>   remove directory "/var/www/emerson-suite/var/cache/de~/pools/rDfZ
>   I1q9aB": .

Complete console output of error:

> Generating autoload files ocramius/package-versions:  Generating
>   version class... ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version
>   class
>
> > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> >     Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>
> // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug  // true
>
> Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]   Failed to
>   remove directory "/var/www/emerson-suite/var/cache/de~/pools/rDfZ
>   I1q9aB": .
>
> cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help]
>   [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi]
>   [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]
>
> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.
>
> [RuntimeException]   An error occurred when executing the
>   "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:    // Clearing the cache for the
>   dev environment with debug    // true
>
> [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]
>   Failed to remove directory "/var/www/emerson-suite/var/cache/de~/pools/rDfZ
>   I1q9aB": .
>
> cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help]
>   [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi]
>   [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV]   [--no-debug] [--]

Tried running composer with both `sudo` and without. 
The command that I ran is: `$ sudo composer require javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle`

Not sure what to do about this, any help is appreciated.

#### Update

My environment is Ubuntu on Vagrant VM on Mac OS X.

Comment: What if you remove the directory yourself? When I run into this kind of problems I perform `rm -rf var/cache/* vendor/*`.

Comment: I know, I've seen a lot of people having a similar issue. I've tried removing the dirs myself, I've stopped all editor/ide but even with a clear folder, the composer install process creates de~ folder in cache dir, so I don't know why that is...

Comment: I have used the instructions on this blog to create a work-around, during installation of new bundles, and then I revert to my previous settings, this is not ideal, am I'm still looking for a permanent solution, but it lets me get the job done for now: https://beberlei.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it could be an issue involving permissions inside the OS and perhaps development environments.

Try looking for the answer here, a lot of people seem to be having this issue.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19363#issuecomment-264655158

Comment: I'm using vagrant and running this as the vagrant user (vagrant ssh)

Comment: Did you try to store the cache and logs outside the shared folder as explained in the linked issue?

Answer (score 0):

The directory **./de~/** is the old /dev/ directory, as it has been moved ready to be deleted. The /pools/ directory is the cache that is being built during the run of the application. On the initial startup, it's using one user-account, but the webserver is running another, and so the original user account does not have permission to delete some files.

The easy way around this - in the dev environment at least - is to `sudo rm -rf .../de~`. When I do remove old versions of code on prod, I'll often have to do the same because there was more than just the original deploying user, writing to the cache directory.